# How to create Instagram type message when posting photo to users timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

If you share a photo on Instagram you see the following message above the photo on your timeline.

*"FB User took a photo with Instagram."*

My test currently just shows:

*"FB User 3 seconds ago via AppName"*

My image Post code is:

```
$args = Array(
    'url'           => 'http://www.mySiteName.com/imageName.png',
    'message'       => 'Made on SiteName http://www.mySiteName.com',
);
$post_id = $this->facebook->api("/me/photos", "post", $args);
```

I think I need to set OpenGraph Actions and Objects, which I've done, but I'm not sure I've set them up correctly or how to test them.

I've created an Action "Make" and an Object "Collection" and tried the following:

```
$post_id = $this->facebook->api("/me/Namespace:make", "post", $args);
```

but get error:

*"The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: collection."*

Collection Get Code gives:

```
 <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# collection: http://ogp.me/ns/collection#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="appId" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="collection" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Collection" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

Action Get Code gives:

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/nameSpace:make?access_token=TOKEN'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it working and have posted below an image of resulting Post, reference URLs and Codeigniter code.

Make is my OpenGraph Action and Collection is my OpenGraph Object.

[image: Resulting Post in Facebook]

**Reference:**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

```
$userId = $this->facebook->getUser();

// If user is not yet authenticated, the id will be zero
if($userId == 0){
    // Generate a login url
    $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_photos,friends_photos,publish_stream')); 
    echo "<h2><a href='" . $url . "'>Login</a></h2>";
} else {

    // Make Logout URL
    $logoutUrl = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
        'next'  => 'http://www.myUrl.com/logout/',
        // URL to which to redirect the user after logging out
    ));
    echo "<h2><a href='" . $logoutUrl . "'>Logout</a></h2>";

    // Get User's data
    $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    echo "<p>Welcome <b>" . $user["name"] . '</b></p>';
    echo("<p><b>User Details: </b>");
    print_r($user);
    echo("</p>");

    // Get user's Permissions 
    $permissions = $this->facebook->api('/me/permissions');
    echo("<p><b>User Permissions: </b>");
    print_r($permissions);
    echo("</p>");

    if (isset($permissions['data'][0]['publish_stream'])) {
        echo "<h3>Permission to Post</h3>";
    } else {
        $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_photos,friends_photos,publish_stream')); 
        echo "<h3>NO Permission to Post: ";
        echo "<a href='" . $url . "'>Get extra permissions</a></h3>";
    }

    // Upload an via OpenGraph Collection Object
    $og_type = 'collection'; // Your Opengraph Object
    $og_title = urlencode('This is my Title');
    $og_description = urlencode('This is my Description');
    $og_image = 'http://www.myUrl.com/big.png'; // At least 480px by 480px 

    $object_url = 'http://www.myUrl.com/fb_object_meta.php?fb:app_id=398917983475605&og:type='.$og_type.'&og:title='.$og_title.'&og:description='.$og_description.'&og:image='.urlencode($og_image);
    // See this URL if you need the code for the dynamic meta data page
    // http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/

    $args = Array(
        'collection'                => $object_url,
        'image[0][url]'             => $og_image, // Possible to upload more than one user gen image e.g. image[1][url]
        'image[0][user_generated]'  => 'true',
        //'message'                 => 'Made on myUrl http://www.myUrl.com', // This shows above the large pic
    );

    try {
        $post_id = $this->facebook->api("/me/myUrl:make", "post", $args);
        print_r($post_id);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the right of where you added your OG actions in the App console there will be a link that says "Get Code". This will show you the information you need to include.

In your case, you should have a parameter in your args which is `collection` which contains the URL of the page containing the OG markup for your photo.

You can find this markup by clicking on the "Get Code" link next to the `collection` object you created in the app console.

**Update**

Open graph works by adding meta tags to the head of an accessible web page. You need to add the `colleation` meta to some page and then in the `collection` parameter in the request you're making, add the URL of the page.

Comment: I've added the two Get Code samples above, but I'm still not sure what I need from them, could you clarify pls?

Comment: looks like you're missing a -F from the Action Get Code.

Comment: I've managed to get it Post using "userId/nameSpace:make?collection=http://www.myUrl.com/collection_meta.html&message=test&image=http://www.myUrl.com/big_pic.png" but it's only showing a small image on the timeline, so doesn't seem to be uploading at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your help getting me started with this.